# ansible lineinfile option throwing error

Tags: python, ansible

I have a file and in that file I want to add the pattern:

```
dogstreams: /root/ddmonitor/pattern.txt:/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/libs/parsers.py:parse_web
```

to the end of the file.

I've tried the following so far:

```
---

- name: Creates directory
  file: path=/root/ddmonitor state=directory owner=root group=root mode=0775

- name: copy the pattern_search.txt file which has patterns to be grepped
  copy: src=pattern_search.txt dest=/root/ddmonitor/pattern_search.txt owner=root group=root mode=755

- name: copy the logsearchtest.sh script which greps patterns and prints pattern.txt file
  copy: src=logsearchtest.sh dest=/root/ddmonitor/logsearchtest.sh owner=root group=root mode=755

- name: schedule cron to run every 5 minutes
  cron: name="logsearch script for grepping pega alert logs" minute="*/5" job="/root/ddmonitor/logsearchtest.sh > /dev/null"

- name: copy parsers.py fucntion to datadog lib path
  copy: src=parsers.py dest=/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/libs/parsers.py owner=root group=root mode=755

- name: copy datadog agent configuration file
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/dd-agent/datadog.conf regexp="^dogstreams: " line="dogstreams: /root/ddmonitor/pattern.txt:/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/libs/parsers.py:parse_web"

- name: wait a bit
  service: name=datadog-agent state=restarted
  when: not datadog_api_key == 'NONE'
```

but when I run my main playbook it shows the following error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/datadog-pegalogs-apptier/tasks/main.yml': line 19, column 65, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: copy datadog agent configuration file
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/dd-agent/datadog.conf regexp="dogstreams: " line="dogstreams: /root/ddmonitor/pattern.txt:/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/libs/parsers.py:parse_web"
                                                                ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes.  If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes.  For instance this arbitrary
example:

    foo: "bad" "wolf"

Could be written as:

    foo: '"bad" "wolf"'
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `template` instead of `lineinfile`, for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Ansible Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html)

I believe that you will need to do something similar to this:

> Fully quoted because of the ': ' on the line. See the Gotchas in the YAML docs.

```
- lineinfile: "dest=/etc/sudoers state=present regexp='^%wheel' line='%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'"
```

There is a YAML limitation to the ":" which is listed [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html)

> You will want to quote any hash values using colons, like so:

```
foo: "somebody said I should put a colon here: so I did"
```

So your line should look like:

```
- name: copy datadog agent configuration file
  lineinfile: "dest=/etc/dd-agent/datadog.conf regexp='^dogstreams: ' line='dogstreams: /root/ddmonitor/pattern.txt:/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/libs/parsers.py:parse_web'"
```

I guess you could escape the colon as {{ ":" }} like so:

```
lineinfile: dest=/etc/dd-agent/datadog.conf regexp="^dogstreams{{ ":" }} " line="dogstreams: /root/ddmonitor/pattern.txt{{ ":" }}/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/libs/parsers.py:parse_web"
```